# Leer property de SpringBoot usando Angular

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

Actualmente tengo un aplicación en Angular6 el cual lee unos parámetros de un archivo.ts.

Me he dado cuenta que cuando haga el `ng build`, se generará una carpeta con los archivos minificados y no se podrán cambiar los valores.

Estos archivos los pego en la carpeta de

```
NombreProyecto\target\classes\static
```

**Para tener el Angular dentro del SpringBoot.**

El archivo del SpringBoot también es externo, pero eso SÍ puedo leerlo con la etiqueta:

```
@PropertySource("file:${ruta_properties}")
```

Al ejecutar

```
rutaArchivos=C....
java -jar -Druta_properties=${rutaArchivos}/application.properties -Dlogging.config=${rutaArchivos}/log4j2.xml NombreProyecto-1.0.jar
```

El problema es que necesito que el Angular lea unas configuraciones del .properties, pero no encuentro como hacerlo en Google, Gracias!

Comment: Te aconsejo crear un recurso REST (algo como `/params/`) para que tu página consulte esos datos a tu servidor.

Comment: Si, estamos barajando eso, pero por si había alguna solución que los archivos puedan leer eso.. gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se me ocurren dos opciones:

- Crear un fichero con los datos (por ejemplo en formato JSON) y añadirlo a la carpeta `/assets` de tu proyecto. De este modo, **después de hacer el build**, el fichero seguirá estando en la carpeta /assets/ generada y podrás cambiarlo sin necesidad de hacer todo el proceso de nuevo. En este caso necesitarías acceder a él vía AJAX:

  ```
  this.httpClient.get<any>('./assets/datos.json').subscribe(datos => {...});
  ```
- Guardar los datos en backend (en un fichero, en una tabla parámetros de la base de datos... etc) y servirlos mediante un recurso REST, que sería algo similar a lo anterior:

  ```
  this.httpClient.get<any>('./api/params/').subscribe(datos => {...});
  ```

Comment: El problema de la primera opción, que cuando haga el .jar del Springboot, ya no se tendría acceso a la carpeta assets XD, hacer una llamada a si mismo para obtener los parámetros será la única opción ...

Comment: ¿Estás metiendo el build de angular en el jar? No pensaba en ese escenario, yo los desplegó por separado

Comment: Para este proyecto sí, se tiene que meter el build del Angular en el java, lo decía en la descripción del post :P